# Repeat footer field on new page

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

The question is simple, I couldn't find any solution though.

If it is possible, how do I repeat a field that's in the Footer on a new page if it doesn't fit the container?

For example: I have a column that can store up to 5000 characters, and I must display it in the Footer. So if it reachs a certain number of characters, I'd like it to be repeated on a new page, even if it's the only field repeated.

Could someone point me to the right direction? Or just tell me if it's not possible?

Oh and it may be put in the Body instead of being in the Footer, if that makes it easier or if it solves the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are unable to display columns in the Page Footer, what I do is create A @MyParam and set it as Internal.  Under Default Values Select "From Query" then select the dataset and set the Value Field to the column one you want to display.

Drag out a TextBox and place it in the page footer, edit the Expression for the TextBox and have it display the @MyParam rather than the column.

This will repeat the entire column, not the "overflow" from the original column.

Comment: What I want is to display only the overflow, because if I display the entire content in a new page, it wouldn't be displayed correclty again. Still, if all you meant was to create a parameter with the column's value and then set a textbox to the parameter instead of setting it to the column directly, and put it in the footer, it didn't work.

Comment: The column value you want to display must be a single row, not multiple values/rows.  To get the overflow onto the next page I would suggest creating a custom function, but again, if you are getting multiple rows back, it may not be possible.

Comment: Yes I am getting a single row. And that's exactly what I want, I want to get the overflow onto the next page. Do you have any tips on how t o achieve this?

Comment: A custom function is the only option I can think of at the moment.  Something that fires on a pagebreak.  Calculate the charter width, and how many characters are returned for that string, cut off the overflow and place it the text box as long as page # > 1.

Comment: Yeah... sounds a little creepy. Thanks!